# How to add elements of a matrix to create a new matrix?

Tags: matlab

Say I have a matrix

```
x = [1 2 3 4 ]
```

and I want to create a matrix that adds two elements and outputs a third?

```
y = [1+2 3+4]
y = [3 7]
```

For four values, I can just do y=[x(1)+x(2) x(3)+x(4)].
How would I go about doing that if x was bigger and variable (say a thousand elements)? How would I program y?

I've been struggling with this for two days now... thanks in advance...

Comment: If you needed more advanced summing like unequal number of elements summed for each `y` , `accumarray` would be the weapon of choice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple way would be to reshape the original array `x` into a matrix containing k rows, k being the number of elements you are summing together (here 2, sorry I don't know how to explain this), and then simply call `sum` on this matrix which will calculate the sum of each column and output it into a new vector `y`.

Example:

```
x = [1:10] 

block = 2

r = reshape(x,block,[])
```

So here `r` looks like this:

```
r =

     1     3     5     7     9
     2     4     6     8    10
```

Therefore calling `sum` with the 1st dimension on `r` yields the following:

```
y = sum(reshape(x,block,[]),1)

y =

     3     7    11    15    19
```

Comment: Wow... Thanks! Reshape is amazing!